# C# equivalent of getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(...)

Tags: c#, dll, embedded-resource

In Java you can read a file embedded inside a JAR-file by using the following code:

```
String file = "com/company/package/filename.txt";
InputStream is = ClassName.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(file);
```

What is the C#/.NET equivalent of the above code - that is, how do I read a file I've embedded inside a DLL?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once you've added the text file as a resource, and assigned a `resourceName` to it, then:

```
 Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
 TextReader inputStream = new StreamReader(assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName));
 string result = inputStream.ReadToEnd();
```

Note: this came from [this](http://gibbons.co.za/archive/2005/02/02/253.aspx) posting

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply!

Do you know if it possible to add a file to a DLL from the command line? I.e. not using Visual Studio. I'm running Mono and would like to add the resources as part of the build process.

Comment: Found the answer: use the -resource flag when running "mcs".